# Replace column by another table

Tags: r

Assuming I have a df looks like below.

```
df <- read.table(textConnection("
id1 id2 id3       inter
  1   2   3       7.343
  6   5   4       2.454
  1   5   6       3.234
"), header = TRUE)
```

And I want to replace column `id1`, `id2`, and `id3` by source dataframe.

```
source <- read.table(textConnection("
sid rid 
  1   a
  2   b
  3   c
  4   43454
  5   2254 
  6   43
"), header = TRUE)
```

If I can find `source$sid` is equal to `df$id1`, `df$id2`, or `df$id3`, 
then I want to replace them as `source$rid`.

As a result I can see.

```
id1 id2 id3 inter
  a   b   c  7.343   
 43 2254 43454 2.454
  a   2254 43  3.234
```

Any hint please?

Comment: Try `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) {i1 <- match(x, source$sid); i2 <- !is.na(i1); x[i2] <- as.character(source$rid)[i1[i2]];x})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tidyverse` to `gather`, `left_join` and then `spread` again, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 gather(var, sid, -inter) %>% 
 left_join(source, by = 'sid') %>% 
 select(-sid) %>% 
 spread(var, rid)

#  inter id1  id2   id3
#1 2.454  43 2254 43454
#2 3.234   a 2254    43
#3 7.343   a    b     c
```

Based on your comment, It seems that you have some duplicates. The following grouping by `var` and creating a `seq` of unique values should suffice (though I can not test since your example does not produce this error),

```
df %>% 
  gather(var, sid, -inter) %>% 
  left_join(source, by = 'sid') %>% 
  select(-sid) %>% 
  group_by(var) %>% 
  mutate(new = seq(n())) %>% 
  spread(var, rid) %>% 
  select(-new)
```

Comment: thanks, but when I use your script to another dataset, I get complains **Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (5464, 5465, 5467.....**, know why?

Comment: @user3058889. Yes you have duplicates (as error states). Try `df %>% gather(var, sid, -inter) %>% left_join(source, by = 'sid') %>% select(-sid) %>% group_by(var) %>% mutate(new = seq(n())) %>% spread(var, rid) %>% select(-new)`

Answer (score 2):

```
tmp <- as.matrix(df[paste0("id", 1:3)]) 
ind <- match(tmp, source$sid)
tmp[] <- as.character(source$rid)[ind]
df[paste0("id", 1:3)] <- tmp
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but your script is only working for first replacement, but if I have repeated elements in my `df` file? Because in my case, I have several repeats in column `id1`, `id2`, and `id3`. I have updated my question. @F. Privé

Comment: I knew I had done something wrong. Try switching the elements in the match and then use tmp[] <- as.character(source$rid)[ind]